# SQLite update field with count from another table

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am trying prepare a table before exporting to CSV however the Sqlite administrator software I am using is reporting invalid syntax.  Anybody see whats gone wrong?

```
UPDATE 'tblTags'
SET 'tagUsageCount' =
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM 'tblTagLinks'
WHERE 'tblTagLinks'.'TLTagId' = 'tblTags'.'tagId')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no semicolon `;` at the end. Otherwise the syntax is valid.

Comment: Thank you, I thought I had tried that but clearly I missed it

Answer (score 0):

[SQLiteSpy](http://www.yunqa.de/delphi/doku.php/products/sqlitespy/index) doesn't report a syntax error.
Can you try to un-stringify the names? ie  `'tblTags' --> tblTags`